# Gerrit OKTA SAML plugin configuration redirecting to login page after successful authentication at OKTA

Tags: saml, gerrit, okta

I configured gerrit as per the documentation https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/saml/
I am able to successfully login at OKTA, but gerrit is redirecting to login page. I am not sure which attribute is causing this redirect.

No logs for SAML plugin.

Comment: how do you try to validate the SSO: by clicking the chiclet in Okta or from Gerrit login page?

Comment: login page.  when I accessed gerrit URL. it is redirecting to OKTA login page. Once login is successful it is redirecting to gerrit../login . What I understand is SAML plugin is not able to validate the successful response. I am not sure where can I check the SAML plugin logs . Nothing in gerrit error_log file

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gerrit, but browser extension `SAML tracer` can help you to analyze SAML exchange and find any discrepancies in the assertion sent by IdP